# Change notification doesn't work on Outlook for Mac OS

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I follow this repository https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-changenotifications  to implement the changes notifying on sent mailbox. So whenever user send a message, I would like receive a notification. Everything work fine if I test it on Windows machine or on outlook web app, however it doesn't work if I test it on Mac OS. Do you have any idea why it could happen?

My testing Mac OS version: macOS Sierra version 10.12.6
Outlook version: Outlook for Mac, version 16.29 (19090802)

Comment: could you share api response or error details ?

Comment: It doesn't call my notification url, so I have no error details. I just wonder that has outlook on mac integrated with microsoft graph api or use exchange api?

Answer (score 0):

The mail change notifications are not tied to the client. The notifications are triggered based on service side events.

If you subscribe to mail change notifications and have it call your own API. It has nothing to do with the client. Its to do with activity happening in the mailbox in the service.

If you are sending a message in MacOS client, can you see the sent message in /messages for sent items? Interesting to see whether the macos client is sync the mailbox changes on the client side back to service side.

Answer (score 0):

For outlook website, check [this](https://www.guidingtech.com/enable-disable-desktop-notifications-outlook-com/) tutorial:

[image]